# How to update the JSF sessionscoped managed bean if i access it?

Tags: jsf-2, session-bean

As title.

The problem is the attribute in the bean is fixed after init().

I want to update the count attribute when ever i access #{managedBean.xyz} method in JSF

I want to stick with the sessionscoped instead of view/request because it saves some time for the Object re-creation.

I don't want to do the attribute update manually in every xyz function. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to invoke a bean method on every view which involves the bean?

Add [`<f:event type="preRenderView">`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/event.html) to those views.

```html
<f:event type="preRenderView" listener="#{managedBean.countUp}" />
```

with

```java
public void countUp() {
    count++;
}
```

It will be invoked only once on every request.